# How to create a link through to database entry

Tags: php, database, forms

I have a page that shows the responses from my form (in a webpage). At the moment, all the responses sit on one page, one after the other. I would like the page to show a list of all the dates submitted (`date_submitted`) and `ID` number and when that is clicked it takes us to a page with that particular response (i.e. the full response). How do I create a link that will take it to this record?

This is my code for that page:

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="surveystyle.css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="container2">
    <div class="logo-header"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="" width="205" height="119" /></div>
    <h2> Guest Questionnaire Responses </h2>
<?php

    try {
            $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***', '***', '***');
            $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        die();
    }

class guestquestionnaireEntry
    {
        public $id, $date_submitted, $choice, $expectations, $res, $res_information, $res_staff, $further_comments1, 
        $entry;

        public function __construct()
            {
                $this->entry = "<a href=\"?ID={$this->id}\">ID</a>
    <tr style='text-align: left; font:arial;'><td><h3>Date Submitted: {$this->date_submitted}</h3></td></tr>

            <BR>
            <table border='1' align='center'>
                <tr style='background: #566890; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'>
                    <td colspan='3'>Prior to Arrival</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                    <td width='60%'>What made you choose us for your recent stay? </td>
                    <td width='40%' colspan='2'>{$this->choice}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                    <td>Did our hotel meet your expectations as advertised? If no, please state why: </td>
                    <td width='40%' colspan='2'>{$this->expectations}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style='background: #566890; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'>
                    <td colspan='3'>Making your Reservation</td>
                </tr>
                <BR>
                <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                    <td>Ease of making your reservation: </td>
                    <td width='40%'>$img</td>
                    <td width='5%'>{$this->res}</td>
                </tr>
                <BR>
                <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                    <td>Hotel information offered: </td>
                    <td width='40%'>$img2</td>
                    <td width='5%'>{$this->res_information}</td>
                </tr>
                <BR>
                <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                    <td>Warmth and friendliness of staff: </td>
                    <td width='40%'>$img3</td>
                    <td width='5%'>{$this->res_staff}</td>
                </tr>
                <BR>
                <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                    <td colspan='3'>Further Comments: </BR></BR>{$this->further_comments1}</td>
                </tr>
                <BR>
            </table>";
            }
    }


// Checks if the submitted is a number. If so, isolates the ID and adds "where" clause
$id      =   (!empty($_GET['ID']) && is_numeric($_GET['ID']))? " where ID = '".$_GET['ID']."'" : "";
// Add the $id to the end of the string
// A single call would be SELECT * FROM guestquestionnaire where ID = '1'
$query   =   $handler->query("SELECT * FROM guestquestionnaire{$id}");
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'guestquestionnaireEntry');

    while($r = $query->fetch()) {
        echo $r->entry, '<br>';
    }
?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a `where` in your sql:

**HTML Button:**

```
<!-- Use whatever here to click on that triggers the ID reload -->
<a href="?ID=<?php echo $this->id; ?>">ID</a>
```

**SQL Query:**

```
// Checks if the submitted is a number. If so, isolates the ID and adds "where" clause
$id      =   (!empty($_GET['ID']) && is_numeric($_GET['ID']))? " where ID = '".$_GET['ID']."'" : "";
// Add the $id to the end of the string
// A single call would be SELECT * FROM guestquestionnaire where ID = '1'
$query   =   $handler->query("SELECT * FROM guestquestionnaire{$id}");
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'guestquestionnaireEntry');
```

**EDIT:**

```
// Should be something like this
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->entry = "
        <a href=\"?ID={$this->id}\">ID</a>...etc.
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this go on the same page as my code listed above? Little confused where to put it.

Comment: Yes, the sql query adds the line and replaces your line. The HTML button would go somewhere in the construct() however you want to lay it out. It's probably more like `<a href="?ID=<?php echo $this->id; ?>">ID</a>` though

Comment: Thanks, I can't seem to get it working though. That last line you updated (the one mentioned in your comment too) gives me a blank page as though there's an error with it.

Comment: Well there probably is an error. Put `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>` at the very top of your page. That will tell you/me what the error is.

Comment: Still gives me a blank page. If I remove that <a href...> line and keep that it loads the page as it should.

Comment: Did you put the `<a href..>` in the `__construct()` body? if not, then you are getting a fatal error regarding the use of `$this` outside of an object.

Comment: Yes, it sits right under  public function __construct() {

Comment: Did you put the `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>` at the very top of the page?

Comment: Yep, very very top. Have just updated my code now with your suggestions. I know I still have a lot of fields in the body that won't need to be once it opens into a new window, but I have kept it in for now until I have it figured out.

Comment: Did you write it with the escaped quotes and braces (`{ }`)?

Comment: Okay, it's loading now with the ID link at the top. But when I click it nothing is happening :/ it just loads this in my URL: www.myurl.com/surveyview.php?ID=

Comment: Ok that's closer. You need it to populate the `$this->id`. You wrote `public $id` so I assume the id is `$this->id` however from what you have written, it's not populating the id number.

Comment: Also, I am guessing when I wrote the add-on to the sql `where ID = `, it may actually be `where id = `, I don't know. This should be something you would have to know based on your ability to access that database table.

Comment: Perfect, turns out it was ID (capital). Seems to be working now; thank you for all your help!! Hugely appreciate!

Comment: No problem, I have actually never seen the way the PDO is able to apply a class from the result of the query, so I learned something new too!

Comment: Oh cool! I learnt it in a tutorial last year. It's the only way I really know how, but I quickly discovered that there's about 1,000 ways to do this :)

Comment: Hi @rasclatt i'm now struggling to hide the rest of the content to only show when they click through the ID. I thought it would be simple but turns out it's not. Any chance you may be able to help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688936/show-additional-form-data-when-result-is-isolated

Comment: Like what is supposed to happen?