# Show Additional Form Data when Result is Isolated

Tags: php, database, pdo

I have a form that displays the results from a survey into a webpage. At the moment, when a user clicks on the 'View Here' it takes them to the individual entry for that ID. When it is clicked I would like it to also show additional results (also part of the results from the same database).

Any idea how I do this? Just to clarify, it should not show until the ID is clicked to single out that entry - otherwise it shows them all in full one after the other.

```
<?php

try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***', '***', '***');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
  }
class guestquestionnaireEntry {
    public $id, $date_submitted, 
        $entry;

        public function __construct()
    {

$this->entry = "

        <table border='1' align='center'>

                 <tr class='tablelist' style='font-size: 8pt;' ><td width='5%' colspan='2'>{$this->ID}</td><td width='40%' colspan='2'><b>Date Received: </b>{$this->date_submitted}</td><td width='45%' colspan='2'>{$this->name}</td><td width='10%'><a href=\"?ID={$this->ID}\">View here</a> </td></tr>

        </table>

";

    }

}

        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_submitted, '%m/%d/%Y') AS date_submitted FROM guestquestionnaire


// Checks if the submitted is a number. If so, isolates the ID and adds "where" clause
$id      =   (!empty($_GET['ID']) && is_numeric($_GET['ID']))? " where ID = '".$_GET['ID']."'" : "";
// Add the $id to the end of the string
// A single call would be SELECT * FROM guestquestionnaire where ID = '1'
$query   =   $handler->query("SELECT * FROM guestquestionnaire{$id}");
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'guestquestionnaireEntry');

while($r = $query->fetch()) {
    echo $r->entry, '<br>';
}

?>
```

Additional code that I would like to show once 'View Here' is clicked (so when the individual entry is shown):

```
class guestquestionnaireEntry {
    public $id, $date_submitted, $choice, $expectations, $res, $res_information, $res_staff, $further_comments1,
        $entry;

public function __construct()
    {

$this->entry = "
         <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td width='60%'><a href=\"?ID={$this->ID}\">ID</a> </td><td width='40%' colspan='2'>{$this->date_submitted}</td></tr>

        <tr style='text-align: left; font:arial;'><td><h3>Date Submitted: {$this->date_submitted}</h3></td></tr>


        <table border='1' align='center'>

        <tr style='background: #566890; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'><td colspan='3'>Prior to Arrival</td></tr>


            <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td width='60%'>What made you choose us for your recent trip? </td><td width='40%' colspan='2'>{$this->choice}</td></tr>

            <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td>Did we meet your expectations as advertised? If no, please state why: </td><td width='40%' colspan='2'>{$this->expectations}</td></tr>


        <tr style='background: #566890; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'><td colspan='3'>Making your Reservation</td></tr><BR>


        <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td>Ease of making your reservation: </td><td width='40%'>$img</td><td width='5%'>{$this->res}</td></tr><BR>

        <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td>Hotel information offered: </td><td width='40%'>$img2</td><td width='5%'>{$this->res_information}</td></tr><BR>

        <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td>Warmth and friendliness of staff: </td><td width='40%'>$img3</td><td width='5%'>{$this->res_staff}</td></tr><BR>

        <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'><td colspan='3'>Further Comments: </BR></BR>{$this->further_comments1}</td></tr>

        <BR>

        </table>

        <BR>
        <p>Back to List</p>

";
```

Comment: So did it all work? You never mentioned if what you originally were trying to do worked out

Answer (score 0):

See if this works. I have not tested it, so make sure you save a copy of whatever you have so far. It requires database credentials to be filled out:

**Classes:**

```
<?php
    interface   Database
        {   
            public  static  function SetConnection($host,$username,$password,$database);
        }

    interface   Questionnaire
        {
            public  function Display();
            public  function DisplaySingle();
        }

    class   MySQLConn implements Database
        {           
            protected   static  $host;
            protected   static  $username;
            protected   static  $password;
            protected   static  $database;

            public      static $connect;

            private function __construct()
                {
                }

            public  static  function SetConnection($host = "***",$username = "***",$password = "***",$database = "***")
                {
                    self::$host     =   $host;
                    self::$username =   $username;
                    self::$password =   $password;
                    self::$database =   $database;
                    self::$connect  =   (!isset(self::$connect))? self::Initialize() : self::$connect;
                }

            private static  function Initialize($use = 'PDO')
                {
                    if($use == 'PDO') {
                            try {
                                    $con    =   new PDO('mysql:host='.self::$host.';dbname='.self::$database, self::$username, self::$password);
                                    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                    return $con;
                                }
                            catch (PDOException $e) {
                                    die($e->getMessage());
                                }
                        }
                    else
                        return new mysqli(self::$host, self::$username, self::$password, self::$database);
                }
        }

    class   guestquestionnaireEntry implements Questionnaire
        {
            public  $id,
                    $date_submitted,
                    $choice,
                    $expectations,
                    $res,
                    $res_information,
                    $res_staff,
                    $further_comments1,
                    $entry;

            public function __construct()
                {
                    if(empty($_GET['focus']))
                        $this->entry = $this->DisplaySingle();
                    else
                        $this->entry = $this->Display();
                }

            public  function DisplaySingle()
                {
                    ob_start(); ?>

                <table border='1' align='center'>
                    <tr class='tablelist' style='font-size: 8pt;' >
                        <td width='5%' colspan='2'><?php echo $this->ID; ?></td>
                        <td width='40%' colspan='2'><b>Date Received: </b><?php echo $this->date_submitted; ?></td>
                        <td width='45%' colspan='2'><?php echo $this->name; ?></td>
                        <td width='10%'><a href="?ID=<?php echo strip_tags($this->ID); ?>&focus=true">View here</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <?php
                    $data   =   ob_get_contents();
                    ob_end_clean();

                    return $data;
                }

            public  function Display()
                {
                    ob_start(); ?>
                    <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                        <td width='60%'><a href="?ID=<?php echo $this->ID; ?>">ID</a></td>
                        <td width='40%' colspan='2'><?php echo $this->date_submitted; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr style='text-align: left; font:arial;'>
                        <td><h3>Date Submitted: <?php echo $this->date_submitted; ?></h3></td>
                    </tr>
                    <table border='1' align='center'>
                        <tr style='background: #566890; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'>
                            <td colspan='3'>Prior to Arrival</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                            <td width='60%'>What made you choose us for your recent trip? </td>
                            <td width='40%' colspan='2'><?php echo $this->choice; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                            <td>Did we meet your expectations as advertised? If no, please state why: </td>
                            <td width='40%' colspan='2'><?php echo $this->expectations; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr style='background: #566890; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; color: #fff;'>
                            <td colspan='3'>Making your Reservation</td>
                        </tr>
                        <BR>
                        <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                            <td>Ease of making your reservation: </td>
                            <td width='40%'>$img</td>
                            <td width='5%'><?php echo $this->res; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <BR>
                        <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                            <td>Hotel information offered: </td>
                            <td width='40%'><?php echo $img2; ?></td>
                            <td width='5%'><?php echo $this->res_information; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <BR>
                        <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                            <td>Warmth and friendliness of staff: </td>
                            <td width='40%'><?php echo $img3; ?></td>
                            <td width='5%'><?php echo $this->res_staff; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <BR>
                        <tr style='font-size: 8pt;'>
                            <td colspan='3'>Further Comments: </BR>
                                </BR>
                                <?php echo $this->further_comments1; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <BR>
                    </table>
                    <BR>
                    <p>Back to List</p>
                    <?php
                    $data   =   ob_get_contents();
                    ob_end_clean();

                    return $data;
                }
        }
?>
```

**To use:**

```
<?php
    //**********************************************************************************
    // Add the classes here by way of include() or just pasted at the top of the page...
    //**********************************************************************************

    // Start up the database connection
    MySQLConn::SetConnection();
    // Assign database connection
    $handler    =   MySQLConn::$connect;
    // Checks if the submitted is a number. If so, isolates the ID and adds "where" clause
    $id         =   (!empty($_GET['ID']) && is_numeric($_GET['ID']))? " where ID = '".$_GET['ID']."'" : "";
    // Add the $id to the end of the string
    // A single call would be SELECT * FROM guestquestionnaire where ID = '1'
    $query      =   $handler->query("SELECT * FROM guestquestionnaire{$id}");
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'guestquestionnaireEntry');
    // Assign data
    while($r = $query->fetch()) {
            $setEntry[] =   $r->entry;
        }
    // Implode with break
    if(isset($setEntry))
        echo implode("<br />",$setEntry);
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. This is just giving me a blank page, I tried adding '<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>' but still completely blank. The comment 'Add the classes here by way of include() or just pasted at the top of the page' confused me. I added the first section 'Classes' then just placed 'To use' underneath the entire thing; perhaps I did that wrong?

Comment: Did u put in db credentials?

Comment: Yes, I put them in here: public  static  function SetConnection($host = "***",$username = "***",$password = "***",$database = "***")

Comment: Inside the `construct()` of `guestquestionnaireEntry` above everything, write `print_r($_REQUEST);`

Comment: Okay that brought back this: Array ( [__utma] => 148261237.26010661.1438191112.1438191112.1438191112.1 [__utmc] => 148261237 [__utmz] => 148261237.1438191112.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none) ) Array ( [__utma] => 148261237.26010661.1438191112.1438191112.1438191112.1 [__utmc] => 148261237 [__utmz] => 148261237.1438191112.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none) ) .... (more text just like this; I can add it above if you need it)

Comment: No, that's good, that means the code is getting to that point (meaning it's not totally failing due to syntax or anything like that). That means likely that the two functions inside the construct, can not do what I had hoped they could do. Take that same `print_r` code and drop it at the bottom of the `DisplaySingle()` function. Remove it from that construct as well so you only have one print_r

Comment: That's doing the same thing (just to confirm I removed it from there and added it just after '$this->entry = $data;'

Comment: Yes, but do `print_r($data);`

Comment: Okay, now I can see the page that I want to (albeit with no design styles) but when I click on the buttons to view it does nothing (URL goes to: '.php?ID=26&focus=true' on the end and the page is blank.

Comment: Ok yeah, then I just updated the `__construct()`, `DisplaySingle()` function, and `Display()` function. Try those 3 changes.

Comment: Oooooo crap. I see what the problem is...at the bottom, should be `echo implode` not just `implode`

Comment: Perfect, that's working - thank you!! It's stripped out all design styles but I can go back in and add that. Thank you again!! For all your help!

Comment: Sorry that was a dumb mistake on my part. Hopefully I've been help and not help add confusion.

Comment: Not at all; you were a great help and I really I appreciate it!!

Comment: Great! you may want to mark you question as answered so folks don't come and try to solve your already-solved problem! Cheers!